# getting attribute of an element with its corresponding Id

Tags: python, xml, lxml, attr

suppose that i have this xml file :

```
<article-set xmlns:ns0="http://casfwcewf.xsd" format-version="5">
<article>
 <article id="11234">
     <source>
     <hostname>some hostname for 11234</hostname>
     </source>
     <feed>
         <type weight=0.32>RSS</type>
     </feed>
     <uri>some uri for 11234</uri>
 </article>
 <article id="63563">
     <source>
     <hostname>some hostname for 63563 </hostname>
     </source>
     <feed>
         <type weight=0.86>RSS</type>
     </feed>
     <uri>some uri  for 63563</uri>
  </article>
.
.
.
</article></article-set>
```

what I want, is to print each article id with its specific attribute weight in RSS for the whole document (like this).

```
id=11234 
weight= 0.32


id=63563 
weight= 0.86
.
.
.
```

I used this code to do so,

```
from lxml import etree
tree = etree.parse("C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\public.xml")


for article in tree.iter('article'):
    article_id = article.attrib.get('id')

    for weight in tree.xpath("//article[@id={}]/feed/type/@weight".format(article_id)):
        print(article_id,weight)
```

and it did not work, could someone help me with this?

Comment: 1) Please copy-paste, never type, your sample program and input data into your question. Your "typos" were substantive and changed the nature of your question. 2) Please include a short, **complete** XML input for testing. When I correct your invalid XML, your test code produces your expected results. Please see [mcve] for more information.

Comment: Also, "it did not work" isn't helpful. What, precisely, was the expected outcome? What, precisely, was the actual outcome?

Comment: sorry, that was an honest mistake. won't happen again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in two lines *if you really want to do so*.

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> tree = etree.parse('public.xml')
>>> for item in tree.xpath('.//article[@id]//type[@weight]'):
...     item.xpath('../..')[0].attrib['id'], item.attrib['weight']
... 
('11234', '0.32')
('63563', '0.86')
```

One xml checker I used insisted on double-quotes around the values for `weight`. `etree` croaked on the xml until I dropped the first line in the file; I don't know why.

Comment: hey Bill, thanks for your reply, and your code looks great, but it does not work for me , it gets stuck in the loop and i'm not sure why.  is it possible that its related to my xml file? because your help for the other problem just worked fine on the same file

Comment: Would you please check your file against one of the xml checkers available on the 'net? It has to be xpath 1.0 to work with Python.

Answer (score 0):

One of these This might work for you:

In this version, note the addition of `=` in the call to `tree.xpath()`:

```
from lxml import etree
tree = etree.parse("news.xml")


for article in tree.iter('article'):
    article_id = article.attrib.get('id')

    for weight in tree.xpath("//article[@id={}]/feed/type/@weight".format(article_id)):
        print(article_id,weight)
```

Here, notice that I replaced `tree.xpath()` with `article.xpath()`:

```
from lxml import etree
tree = etree.parse("news.xml")

for article in tree.iter('article'):
    article_id = article.attrib.get('id')

    for weight in article.xpath("./feed/type/@weight"):
        print(article_id,weight)
```

Comment: the first one , actually that was a typo and i forgot to put '=' in here, so basically the first one is as same as what i got here. but for the second one i ran it , and it did not work. i guess there is a problem in the logic of the  expression. (it gives no error when i run it)